# Sequential asynchronous reads using Stream.BeginRead

Tags: c#, asynchronous, stream, locking

I'm writing a class that exposes a subsection of a stream for reading. Since data may be read from multiple different subsections at the same time, only one operation may be active at any one time.

I had the idea of locking the underlying stream before every operation. Is locking the stream around the `BeginRead` call sufficient to ensure that concurrent asynchronous reads from different positions in the underlying stream happen correctly?

```
public sealed class SubStream : Stream
{
    // ...

    public override IAsyncResult BeginRead(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count,
        AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        lock (this.baseStream)
        {
            this.baseStream.Seek(this.offset + this.position, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return this.baseStream.BeginRead(buffer, offset, count,
                callback, state);
        }
    }

    public override int EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        int read;
        lock (this.baseStream)
        {
            read = baseStream.EndRead(asyncResult);
            this.position += read;
        }
        return read;
    }

    // Read() and ReadByte() also lock on this.baseStream (not shown).

    // ...
}
```

For example, if thread A calls `BeginRead`, a lock on the base stream is acquired. Now thread B calls `BeginRead` and has to wait for the lock to be released. Thread A sets the position of the base stream and starts an asynchronous read operation. Then releases the lock. Thread B then acquires the lock and changes the position of the base stream and starts another asynchronous read operation. Then, sometime later, the asynchronous read from thread A completes. Can I be sure that this reads from the original position in the base stream? If not, how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you considered using a `ReaderWriterLockSlim`? Especially the `EnterWriteLock` part of it fits your description of forcing other threads to wait perfectly.

Comment: @aevitas I don't think that would work. Since reading may happen at different positions in the base stream, only one read operation can be active at any one time.

Comment: I see, that sounds like you may need an asynchronous semaphore then. Your current code should work if you used `async` and `await`, in which case the lock would hold until your operation returns. In this case, I don't think it does. The `SemaphoreSlim` class has a `WaitAsync` method which is probably interesting for you.

Comment: No, this is quite problematic.  For one, locking on the stream object buys you deadlock potential, you don't own that object.  You should wrap it so you can associate it with a private lock object.  For another, if the lock is ever taken then the odds that BeginRead() will throw is very, very high.  Which is a *bug*, the client code isn't negotiating access to the stream properly.  You should always make lots and lots of noise when you detect a threading bug.  Wrap a semaphore as well.  Which gives you the option for Wait(0) + throw to report the bug.  Or Wait() to always make it safe.

Comment: @HansPassant I looked in the implementation of `Stream+SyncStream` in mscorlib, and there they also lock on the wrapped stream and also wrap the call to `BeginRead` in a lock. I may not own the object, but by locking on it I can be sure that other objects that lock on the stream (other instances of my `SubStream`, or an instance of .NET's `SyncStream`) work correctly. Also, why would `BeginRead` throw? When the lock is taken, the thread will block until it is released. Otherwise, the execution is no different from the same code without the lock.

Comment: Sure, it took Microsoft a while to recognize the .NET 1.0 design mistakes.  The Synchronized() methods were a big blunder, live and learn.  Not otherwise a good reason to blindly repeat the mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Here you might end up with multiple threads calling `BeginRead` on the same instance of resource (`baseStream`). As per MSDN, the *"EndRead must be called exactly once for every call to BeginRead. Failing to end a read process before beginning another read can cause undesirable behavior such as deadlock."* In you case, I recon a trouble 'if `Thread B` is on `Seek` (on baseStream) while `Thread A` in the middle of executing their `EndRead(callback)`'.

Due to the nature of requirement, you are better off with wrapping multi-threaded access with synchronous I/O. This means, the current implementation can be amended with synchronous I/O instead of asynchronous I/O. Also, you may want to consider informing queuing threads about the completion of former threads using `Monitor.WaitOne (baseStream)` and `Monitor.Pulse(baseStream)` or `Monitor.PulseAll(baseStream)`.

Alternately, I would like to throw another idea of [Memory-Mapped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) file for segmented style.

Answer (score 0):

In the given code snippet you'll read multiple times from the same position. Move the position update to the `BeginRead` function. Apart from that you are honoring the contract of the `FileStream` class by never concurrently calling its methods.